# In emacs, can I use alternation in the regexp for align-regexp?

Tags: regex, emacs, alignment, text-alignment

For example, I have the following snippet:

```
'abc' => 1,  
'abcabc' =>2,  
'abcabcabc' => 3,
```

And I want to format it to:

```
'abc'       => 1,  
'abcabc'    => 2,  
'abcabcabc' => 3,
```

I know there are easier ways to do it but here I'm just want to practice my understanding of `align-regexp`. I've tried this command but it does not work:

```
C-u M-x align-regexp \(\s-+\)=\|\(>\s-*\)\d 1 1 y
```

Where I'm wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: @phils Yes I know that. That is exactly what I want. My question is that it does not work the way it supposed to.

Comment: @phils, Thanks for pointing the `\d` issue. I forgot emacs does not support it. I'll try to see if I can improve the regex. Thanks again!

Comment: n.b. Converted all that into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the question is: With `\(\s-+\)=\|\(>\s-*\)\d` matching `\(\s-+\)=` *or* `\(>\s-*\)\d`<sup>1</sup>, can we use `align-regexp` to align on *each* of those alternatives throughout a line.

The answer is no -- `align-regexp` modifies one specific matched group of the regexp. In this case it was group 1, and group 1 is the `\(\s-+\)` at the beginning. Group 1 of the regexp does not vary depending on what was actually matched, and so it never refers to `\(>\s-*\)`<sup>2</sup>.

If you can express your regexp such that it really is a single group of the regexp which should be replaced for *every* match throughout the line, you can get the effect you want, however.

e.g. `>?\(\s-*\)[0-9=]` would -- at least for the data shown -- give the desired result.

<sup>1</sup> In Emacs `\d` matches `d`. That should be `[0-9]`.
<sup>2</sup> You *generally* don't want any non-whitespace in the alignment group, as Emacs replaces the content of that group.